# Form validation on client then server

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, web, vuejs2

I'm designing a web application with vue.js and REST Services (java).

I have a very complex form:
- type checks : email is a well formatted email
- password checks : password textfield and retype password textfield matches?
- 2 dropdowns: if I select option A in dropdown 1, in dropdown 2, option {R,T} should appear only.

So, a simple way to deal with this would be:
1. perfect proper checks on client with javascript or some vue plugin.
2. Recheck all on server to make sure nobody "hacked" the json submitted.

The main issue is that I will code twice the checks.

What could be a better approach?

Best regards

Comment: There is no another way to do that. You have to check twice on your selected framework. You can do that on another framework. For instance, on MVC you can set restrictions on Models and it checks it selves on server side and client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you comment, for security reasons, **you can't skip the backend form validation**.

Then, you have to consider if it worth to validate the form in the frontend (Vue) part. Usually is a usability question (show better error messages, change input color, etc.) before submitting. There are several libraries that could help you with this purpose, like

- vue-validator: This is the most popular one, developed by Kazuya
  Kawaguchi, one of the Vue‘s core members. (not compatible yet with
  Vue 2)
- vue-form-generator: A Vue.js plugin that also builds forms along with validation. I’ve already written a mini-tutorial about it on Vue.js Feed.
- vee-validate: Is a new module which is compatible with both Vue 1 and Vue 2. It looks very promising and is the one I will use in this
  tutorial.
- Vuelidate: Simple, lightweight model-based validation for Vue.js 2.0

Extracted from [here](https://m.dotdev.co/form-validation-using-vue-js-2-35abd6b18c5d) and several more (check github).

Vue provide a build-in form validation features either (input type, expected input (string, number, etc.)) and you can take advantge from computed properties to perform more complex calculations (i.e valid email) and show/hide the error as the user fill the form.

I usually do the double check, basic validation in the form (types, invalid chars, max-length, min-length, etc.) and in the backend.  But in the end is up to your decision.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

No matter what, you should be keeping the validation atleast on server.

**Easiest way:**
Keep validation on server, send error message when you get invalid data.
On client side, you can just show the error message received from server to the user in a red colored label so the user will know what went wrong.

**Good way:**
Keep validation on both client and server. The user should know if something is invalid before the form is submitted to the server.

**Why both client and server:**
If something is missed, or the user bypasses the UI validation, the server will handle the REST.
Someone might even be using just the API, and not your form, then they need to know what went wrong.